# Group and count values in an array into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, group-by

I have the following information in a form of Array

```
0: { first: "sea",      second: "deniz",   languageId: "English-Turkish"}
1: { first: "play",     second: "oynamak", languageId: "English-Turkish"}
2: { first: "swim",     second: "yuzmek",  languageId: "English-Turkish"}
3: { first: "foo",      second: "bar",     languageId: "German-Russian"}
4: { first: "computer", second: "l'ordi",  languageId: "English-French"}
```

I need to group them by `languageId` and count the items which belong to these groups.
I also have the following Object for this,

```
export class stats{
    name: String;
    count: number;
}
```

At the end I need the following information;

```
0: { name: "English-Turkish",  count: 3 }
1: { name: "German-Russian",   count: 1 }
2: { name: "English-French",   count: 1 }
```

Array.reduce function looks like a good way to do that to me, but could not figure it out. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Array.reduce` function looks like a good way to do that to me, but
> could not figure it out. How can I implement this?

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get your expected value with more elegant way like below:

```js
const items = [
  { first: "sea",      second: "deniz",   languageId: "English-Turkish"},
  { first: "play",     second: "oynamak", languageId: "English-Turkish"},
  { first: "swim",     second: "yuzmek",  languageId: "English-Turkish"},
  { first: "foo",      second: "bar",     languageId: "German-Russian"},
  { first: "computer", second: "l'ordi",  languageId: "English-French"},
];

const result = items.reduce((acc, {languageId}) => 
{
  acc[languageId] = acc[languageId] || {name: languageId, count: 0};
  // The more elegant way: acc[languageId] ??= {name: languageId, count: 0};
  acc[languageId]['count'] += 1;
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

> The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on
> each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, array.reduce probably isn't the right tool for this.

But is this what you are looking for? You could turn it into a function if you needed to use it frequently.

```js
let items = [
  { first: "sea",      second: "deniz",   languageId: "English-Turkish"},
  { first: "play",     second: "oynamak", languageId: "English-Turkish"},
  { first: "swim",     second: "yuzmek",  languageId: "English-Turkish"},
  { first: "foo",      second: "bar",     languageId: "German-Russian"},
  { first: "computer", second: "l'ordi",  languageId: "English-French"},
];
let grouped = {};
for (let item of items) {
  let { languageId } = item;
  if (!(languageId in grouped)) {
    grouped[languageId] = [];
  }
  grouped[languageId].push(item);
}
let counts = Object.entries(grouped).map(([name, arr]) => ({ name, count: arr.length }));
console.log(counts);
```

This has both `grouped` and `counts`, so if you needed them all grouped together; it has that too.