# Want to find the amount of unique and duplicate objects from an array and list them in a specific way

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

```js
[
 { "id":5,
  "name": "banana"
 },
 { "id":5,
  "name": "banana"
 },
 { "id":4,
  "name": "apple"
 },
 { "id":1,
  "name": "strawberry"
 },
 { "id":1,
  "name": "strawberry"
 }
]
```

`const arrayMap = new Map(Array.map(i => [i.id, {...i, amount: 0 }]));`

Only have one method I've considered, such as mapping the array and assigning an amount per object using a loop but I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it, and the string part is still something I haven't been able to figure out.

Order would be by highest ID number. The array could be seen as a shopping cart, you can have multiple bananas, and they'd just be listed under the same part of the string.

If you have 2 bananas with the ID 5, 1 apple with the ID 4, and 2 strawberries with the ID 1 it would display as such:

However, in my example the "banana" isn't what makes it unique, it would be the ID. There would be no other bananas with different IDs, they would all be added with the same ID as duplicate objects.

`"2x Banana, 1x Apple, 2x Strawberry"`

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: What determines the order of results?

Comment: Code goes in your question, not the comments. Please [edit] it

Comment: @Phil the order of results would be determined by higher id number

Comment: Edited as per request

Comment: But what happens if the same `name` has different `id` values? Please [edit] your question with details on the ordering criteria with examples of different inputs and outputs

Comment: Your two examples don't match up. Why is the first ordered by id lowest to highest and the second highest to lowest?

Comment: What happens if there's 2 bananas with ID 5 and 1 banana with ID 3?

Comment: Sorry about that, I worded it poorly originally. 

In my example, there would be no objects with the same name.

As for the examples, I will edit to the 2nd one only.

Comment: _"there would be no objects with the same name"_... then every count would be 1?

Comment: we'd be matching by ID, not name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group and count values in an array into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66522228/group-and-count-values-in-an-array-into-an-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sort the array by ID, highest to lowest
2. Reduce the sorted array to an object keyed by `id` with `name` and `count` values. Name conflicts if any can be resolved by first-seen.
3. Map those entries to strings then join the whole thing together

```js
const data = [{"id":5,"name":"banana"},{"id":5,"name":"banana"},{"id":4,"name":"apple"},{"id":1,"name":"strawberry"},{"id":1,"name":"strawberry"}];

const capitalise = (str) => str.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, (c) => c.toUpperCase());

const counts = data
  .toSorted((a, b) => b.id - a.id) // sort by ID highest to lowest
  .reduce((acc, { id, name }) => {
    acc[id] ??= {
      name,
      count: 0,
    };
    acc[id].count++;
    return acc;
  }, {});

const str = Object.values(counts)
  .map(({ name, count }) => `${count}x ${capitalise(name)}`)
  .join(", ");

console.log(str);
```

---

If [Array.prototype.toSorted()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted) isn't available, you can either

- Not care about altering the order of the original array and just use `Array.prototype.sort()`
- Break the original array reference using either `[...data]` or `data.slice(0)` then use `.sort()`

Comment: I missed the tag of this being a node.js project so .toSorted() isn't an option. I apologize for the confusion, it's my first time on this site.

Comment: @Ladizi `Array.prototype.toSorted()` is available in Node.js 20.0.0

Comment: You've reminded me to update Node.js. Sorry, again.. lol

Comment: @Ladizi I've added options if you can't upgrade Node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by looping through the array. For example,

```
const data = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "item1" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "item1" },
  { "id": 3, "name": "item3" },
  { "id": 4, "name": "xd" }
];

// Create an object to store item counts
const itemCounts = {};

data.forEach((item) => {
  const itemName = item.name;
  itemCounts[itemName] = (itemCounts[itemName] || 0) + 1;
});

const sortedItems = Object.entries(itemCounts)
  .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
  .map(([itemName, count]) => `${count}x ${itemName}`)
  .join(' ');

console.log(resultString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "banana"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "banana"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "strawberry"
  }
];

let obj = {};

function findDuplicate(data) {
  data.map((e, i) => {
    let {
      id,
      name
    } = e;
    let val = 0;
    if ([name] in obj) {
      obj[name] = obj[name] + 1;
    } else {
      obj[name] = 1
    }
  })
  let output = '';
  let arr = Object.keys(obj);
  for (let x in obj) {
    if (arr.slice(-1) == x) {
      output += `${obj[x]}x ${x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1)}`
    } else {
      output += `${obj[x]}x ${x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1)}, `;
    }
  }
  return output;
}
console.log(findDuplicate(data));
```